# merge two lists of lists to one list of lists

Tags: python

I need to sample 20 values from two multivariate normal distributions (10 each).

Now I have two list of lists **dat1, dat2** which look like

```
# means
m1, m2 = [2, 2], [1, -1]
# covariance
cv1, cv2 = [[0.8, 0.4], [0.4, 0.8]], [[1.3, -0.7], [-0.7, 1.3]]
dat1 = np.random.multivariate_normal(m1, cv1, 10)
dat2 = np.random.multivariate_normal(m2, cv2, 10)

>>>dat1
array([[2.41897704, 1.01060023],
       [2.59949247, 1.93349966],
       [2.65142916, 2.58018331],
       [2.17005156, 3.17732589],
       [3.02638605, 2.8026237 ],
       [2.98480009, 3.27263144],
       [2.43494798, 1.88818356],
       [3.3352379 , 2.22139406],
       [1.47718545, 1.77338061],
       [0.21706158, 2.74841337]])
```

If I try

```
TRAINING_DATA = [c+d for c, d in zip(dat1, dat2)]
```

I get

```
>>>TRAINING_DATA
[array([ 3.57377544, -0.89898446]), array([4.11181782, 0.23353741]), ...]
```

How I can append dat2 to dat1 so that it looks like

```
>>>TRAINING_DATA
array([[3.57377544, -0.89898446],
       [4.11181782, 0.23353741],
       ...
       ])
```

Comment: So you would like in an order of indexes? Could say index 0 in each list, end up returned as `[3.57377544, -0.89898446 4.11181782, 0.23353741]`?

Comment: thx for answering. I want just append all arrays from dat2 to the dat1 array. In the end i want an array which has all my arrays from dat1 and dat2 in the TRAINING_DATA array. Index 0 would return [2.41897704, 1.01060023], because its from dat1, and index 10 would return [3.57377544, -0.89898446]. So I would have all 20 arrays together in the TRAINING_DATA array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try concatenating the two arrays together, this will append `dat2`, to `dat1`.

```
TRAINING_DATA = np.concatenate((dat1, dat2), axis=0)

[[ 1.50548361  1.48826683]
 [ 2.29344     3.53410247]
 [ 3.19513868  0.94069523]
 [ 1.81553839  0.61394121]
 [ 1.84940489  2.51819747]
 [ 1.9253743   2.01885069]
 [ 2.19767682  1.81290866]
 [ 2.6041682   2.04656255]
 [ 1.14421244  1.43839062]
 [ 2.12712095  1.50493227]
 [ 0.0252174  -1.54414803]
 [ 1.94548543 -1.71105078]
 [ 0.42478946 -0.65312376]
 [ 0.18242194 -1.08179918]
 [-0.33842747 -1.39057522]
 [-0.19844272  0.28873601]
 [-0.03024569 -1.20532982]
 [ 2.91372093 -1.90649743]
 [ 0.64701937 -1.90869586]
 [ 0.99986509 -0.92723385]]
```

Read the docs: [numpy.concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)